# Развертывание приложения с локальной БД без установки SQL Server Compact 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio

Добрый вечер, уважаемые форумчане.
Веду разработку приложения `Windows Form (32х\64х)` используя VS2012.
Использую подход - модель первая. 
Использую `EntityFramework 4.4.0.0`.
Использую локальную базу данных `SQL Server Compact 4.0`.
Создал модель>из нее POCO классы и базу данных. Приложение работает на ура, но есть одно НО.
Требуется предустановленный `SQL Server Compact 4.0`. Собственно вычитал, что приложения с такой БД можно развернуть и без установки сервера (используя его исполняемые файлы)
Потрудился весь день над интеренетом, экспериментами, но так и не смог обеспечить запуск приложения на компьютере без предустановленного `SQL Server Compact 4.0`.
Есть желание создать портативное приложение (у пользователей нет прав администратора).
Поделитесь опытом как все таки подсунуть сборки `SQL Server Compact 4.0` в проект и натравить на них `EntityFramework`?

Answer (score 2):

Вот описание от самого Microsoft, как это сделать: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983326.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ничего не читать используйте NuGet, который сделает за пару кликов все за вас при простом добавлении зависимости =)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ как сделать так, что бы все работало тут:
http://erikej.blogspot.ru/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html
Проект, только WPF там выложен..ну и еще куча всякой информации. Пользуйтесь. Описание с майкрасовта читал..не смог заставить его работать.
Всем спасибо).